# python idle 2.7.9 gives a false syntax error

Tags: python, python-idle

I have a file: pytest.py which is one line:

```
print "hello world"
```

idle -r pytest.py

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  8 2015, 15:12:41) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.4.1 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot1-final 208032)] on freebsd10
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
*** Error in script or command!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytest.py", line 1
    print "hello world"
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

running idle with no options, opening and running the file works. This is on FreeBSD 10.0 and py27-gtk2-2.24.0_3 (python binding). This stopped working at some point but I can not relate it to a specific change. All packages/port are up-to-date

Comment: Please post the script itself.

Comment: Try using print as a function and see if that works... that way you rule out the possibility of Python 3 actually running.

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces before `print`. It must be the very frist thing on the line.

Comment: Is there something else in that file? It's working for me, and I have Python 2.7.6

Comment: @MikeMüller That'll result in an IndentationError So it is unlikely to be that

Comment: I can reproduce it and adding parentheses helps. No idea why, though. It does say "Python 2.7.9" at the top for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

Idle compiles the `-r` code [as follows](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/idlelib/PyShell.py#L654):

```
code = compile(source, filename, "exec")
```

However, by default, `compile` [inherits the calling code's future settings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile):

> The optional arguments flags and dont_inherit control which future statements (see PEP 236) affect the compilation of source. If neither is present (or both are zero) the code is compiled with those future statements that are in effect in the code that is calling compile()

Since idle's PyShell.py module [does enable](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/idlelib/PyShell.py#L1)  the [print_function future flags](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html), this means that by accident all of your code in `-r` has to use it to.

Change your code to `print("Hello world")` to fix the problem. As a nice side effect, your code will work in Python 3.x as well.

Comment: This is a bug.  Simple test case: `py -2 -m idlelib.idle -c "print True"`. I opened `https://bugs.python.org/issue24222`  and plan to add "dont_inherit=True".

Comment: Fix applied.  Thanks for the diagnosis.

Answer (score 3):

I caused this problem when I added

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

to the top of PyShell.py as part of backporting the bugfix in [Issue 22420](https://bugs.python.org/issue22420). The fix, which I just applied in [Issue 24222](https://bugs.python.org/issue24222), is this change to line 655.

```
-        code = compile(source, filename, "exec")
+        code = compile(source, filename, "exec", dont_inherit=True)
```

Thanks to 'phihag' for pointing out the problem line.

Answer (score 0):

> from **future** import print_function
>
> print "hello world"

gives the same result on my system

Oh poo can't use vi  -- the answer was correct